# Deploy Next.js app to Firebase Functions with existing functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

Following a few tutorials [like this one](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/deploying-next-js-application-on-firebase-platform-using-cloud-function-with-firebase-hosting-920157f03267), I was able to deploy my `Next.js` app to Firebase Hosting/Functions. Here's the reduced folder structure of my project:

```
myApp
  node_modules // Next.js app dependencies
  .next // destination of npm run build of the Next.js project
  pages // Next.js pages
  functions
    lib // this is where the functions compile
    node_modules // functions' dependencies
    src
      app.ts
      index.ts
      other.ts
    package.json
  public // Next.js app public files
  firebase.json
  package.json
  ...
```

When I run `firebase deploy`, it compiles `functions` into its `lib` folder and deploys everything successfully.

However, when I try to visit the url of my web app, I get `Error: could not handle the request`. When I looked into the Firebase Functions log, I can see an error saying `Error: Cannot find module 'react'`. So, I added `react` to `functions/package.json`, `npm install` and `firebase deploy` successfully again. However, another error, but this time it says `Cannot find module 'react-dom'`.

My understanding is that the reason for this is that my Next.js app relies on all the dependencies listed in my `package.json` in my `root` folder (a reduced list below):

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-prismjs": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^8.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "next-i18next": "^8.5.5",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "prismjs": "^1.24.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "recharts": "^2.0.10",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  }
```

while my `functions/package.json` was, obviously, much shorter:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

I assume the errors would have asked me to duplicate all the dependencies into the `functions/package.json` file, which I obviously don't want.

Alternatively, I can add `firebase-functions` and other relevant dependencies from `functions/package.json` to `root/package.json`, and have the next server setup in the root folder as well. However, how do I include the other existing cloud functions?

Here's how the contents of my `functions/src` files look:

**index.ts**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()

export * from './app' // next.js
export * from './other'
```

**other.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

exports.onUserCreate = functions.database.ref...
// my other cloud functions, such as db triggers, https functions, etc.
```

**app.ts**

```
import next from 'next'
import {https} from 'firebase-functions'

const server = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  conf: {distDir: '.next'}
})

const nextjsHandler = server.getRequestHandler()

exports.app = https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  await server.prepare()
  return await nextjsHandler(req, res)
})
```

Also, here's my `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "target": "myApp",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }]
  }
}
```

How do I deploy the `Next.js` app correctly and make sure my other cloud functions continue to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could lift the `/functions` directory to your project's root directory, this would mean that your other functions are unnecessarily bloated with all of your `Next.js` app's dependencies.

When you deploy a Cloud Function, everything in the configured deployment directory (`/functions` by default) is deployed - even if you don't use it. It is also deployed once for each function. So if you had a 10MB file to your functions directory, every function's deployed size would increase by 10MB. This is what I mean by "bloating" a function.

FYI: You can change the deployed functions directory by adding the following to your `firebase.json` file ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions)):

```json
"functions": {
  "source": "." // <- the project's root directory
}
```

Instead, you should make use of [partial deployment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions). In this situation you'd move `app.ts` to your Next project's directory and leave the other functions that don't depend on your Next deployment in the `/functions` folder. If you deploy your entire project directory, you will end up deploying `/functions` too even though you don't use it, so you should instead move your Next front-end and functions into its own folder.

The file structure will look similar to (details below):

```
/myApp
  /functions
    /lib            // this is where the functions compile
    /node_modules   // functions' dependencies
    /src
      index.ts
      other.ts
    firebase.json   // configuration for this folder's contents
    package.json    // configuration for this folder's contents
  /next
    /node_modules   // Next.js app dependencies
    /.next          // compiled Next.js project
    /pages          // Next.js pages
    /public         // Next.js app public files
    /functions-lib
      app.js        // compiled Next function
    /functions-src
      app.ts        // source of Next function
    firebase.json   // configuration for this folder's contents
    package.json    // configuration for this folder's contents
    ...
```

Your `/functions` folder's `firebase.json` file would look similar to:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

To get the above structure to behave properly, you need to tweak the configuration of the `firebase.json` and `package.json` files.

Add the following to the `/function` folder's `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:otherFunc1,functions:otherFunc2",
  ...
}
```

You could also export these functions as a single group for easy deployment, but the functions will be named like `otherFunctions-otherFunc1`, `otherFunctions-otherFunc2`, and so on:

```js
// index.ts
import * as otherFunctions from './other.ts';
export { otherFunctions };
```

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:otherFunctions",
  ...
}
```

Your `/next` folder's `firebase.json` file would look similar to:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "target": "myApp",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }]
  }
}
```

Add the following (or similar) to the `/next` folder's `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:functions",
  "build:functions": "tsc",
  "build:next": "next build",
  "lint": "npm run lint:next && npm run lint:functions",
  "lint:functions": "eslint --ext .js,.ts ./functions-src",
  "lint:next": "...",
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only hosting,functions:app"
}
```

With the above changes, drop into the appropriate directory and use `npm run deploy` whenever you would use `firebase deploy`.

---

**Note:** Don't forget that Cloud Functions [consume the bodies of requests automatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request), so make sure you account for this when using body parsers in Next projects and testing locally with `next start`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such an elaborate response! I'll give this approach a go. Only if I have two separate folders with functions in them, I assume I will need to deploy from each of them separately? Won't that, however, overwrite each others' functions? Normally when I deploy functions having deleted one, firebase-cli detects that and deletes that functions in the cloud. Or perhaps using partial deployments avoids this exact thing?

Comment: @artooras The partial deployments avoid that exact thing. It won't bother checking if your local function list of all your functions doesn't match the deployed list of all your functions, it only cares about the ones you name. It's also why you use `npm run deploy` with the corresponding `package.json` file.

Comment: By the way, thanks for pointing out that everything in the designated functions directory gets deployed for each function, something I saw confirmed here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: So, I got it working with the following differences. (1) I kept all files in the project root, and then I simply included the _functions_ folder in the _ignore_ part of the firebase.json in the root. (2) I needed to add _.firebaserc_ file in the _functions_ folder to indicate my project. (3) I'm deploying the _app.js_ without explicitly building it, I just edited it use _require_ instead of _import_, and that was enough. So, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @samthecondingman Would you mind looking at my follow-up issue? I didn't want to continue in the comments here, so I created it as a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711863/firebase-functions-do-not-build-next-js-project-when-deployed