# Firebase Functions do not build Next.js project when deployed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I'm able to deploy my Next.js project to Firebase Functions successfully as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680888/deploy-next-js-app-to-firebase-functions-with-existing-functions). However, when I try to visit my project in the browser, I get a `Error: could not handle the request` error, and in the Functions log I see this error message:

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/workspace/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at Server.readBuildId (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:151:355)
    at new Server (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:3:120)
    at NextServer.createServer (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:1:2935)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this though... Adding below my config files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "server.js", // my next.js app init file
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099 next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build",
    "build:functions": "tsc",
    "lint": "npm run lint:next && npm run lint:functions",
    "lint:functions": "eslint --ext .js",
    "lint:next": "next lint",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only database,hosting,functions:nextServer",
    "emulate": "firebase emulators:start --import=./emulator-data --export-on-exit",
    "test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles",
    "cypress": "cypress open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // including next
  }
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "runtime": "nodejs10",
    "ignore": [
      "**/.next/cache/**",
      "**/__tests__/**",
      "**/components/**",
      "**/cypress/**",
      "**/emulator-data/**",
      "**/functions/**",
      "**/layouts/**",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/pages/**",
      "**/public/**",
      "**/utils/**",
      "**/.*",
      "**/*.log",
      "**/cypress.json",
      "**/database.rules.json",
      "**/firebase.json"
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build:functions"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "target": "my_app",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "nextServer"
    }]
  }
}
```

I assume that, once deployed, Firebase Functions environment would run `npm run build` and `npm run start` scripts. Or is the workflow different? Perhaps my scripts are incorrect?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build` in `predeploy` to build the app?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing it to `run build`, alas, same result...  So, are `predeploy` scripts the ones that are run on cloud functions server once deployed? If so, the naming would be very confusing, could be better named post-deploy or something similar...

Comment: For completeness, you should add `server.js` in its current form to this question rather than rely on someone looking at the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68680888/3068190).

Comment: I've actually narrowed down my issue to the `ignore` section of the `firebase.json`. The problem is that when I include `**/pages/**`, it not only ignores that top-level pages folder, but also .next/server/pages, making my deployment incomplete. Ignoring just the `/pages/**` doesn't work for some reason either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) in `package.json` files, the `predeploy` and `postdeploy` lines are executed before and after a call to `firebase deploy` when using the Firebase CLI ([documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#hooks)).

When the Firebase CLI uploads your code to the Cloud Functions staging servers, it is expected to have already been compiled and only needs its runtime dependencies installed. Once an upload has completed, the staging server will execute `npm install --production` and then prepare your function to handle requests (essentially performing a cold-start, without actually executing the function). If either step fails, you will be shown an error like you have. If both steps succeed, your code with the dependencies installed is persisted as an image and saved to Cloud Storage, ready to use when requests to be handled come in.

In your case, the error seems to be that your `.next` folder is missing the compiled version of your application.

There are two possible causes of this, either your build prior to deployment is incomplete or when your files are uploaded, something in your `ignore` list that is required by the deployed code is missing.

For the first part, you modified the `predeploy` hook in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685420/3068190) from:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

incorrectly to:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build:functions"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

By changing this, you aren't building your next app prior to deploying the code to the staging server.

In regards to the second part, the deployed next application may be missing some of its dependencies - you can either fine tune the `ignore` list or you can perform the `next build` step on the server using a `postinstall` script in your `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "main": "server.js", // my next.js app init file
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:next": "next build",
    ...
    "postinstall": "npm run build:next"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // including next
  }
}
```

**Note:** If your `main` file is just JavaScript, you no longer need the typescript compile step defined in `npm run build:functions` and it can be removed.

Comment: The issue was indeed with my `ignore`configuration. The way I wrote it in my original post was removing the `pages`directories from the `.next` directory as well, hence ending up in deploying an incomplete build directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was this error, my solution was:

First, in the packege.json file, in the section scripts, we must modify the property “build”: "next build && next export", and a new property "export": "next export"

Second, we must establish the component and data folders in the root of the project

Third: use the command:
a)You must make log in, so type: firebase login

```
  b)select de option "Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set 
                      up GitHub Action deploys"
  c)in the question:  if you have a build process 
                      for your assets, use your build's output directory?
                      What do you want to use as your public directory?
     
     You must type:   out  (really important, it's a folder output) 
  d) You must type:   npm run build
  f) last step: type: firebase deploy
```

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QTAM.png)
[out folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT2K0.png)